# change CHtml::dropDownList to $form->dropDownList

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii

view

```
 <div class="form">

 <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'sendmessage-form',
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
),
 )); ?>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'receiverType'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'receiverType',array(1 => 'type1' ,2=>'type2'),
    array(
        'empty'=>"",
        'value'=>'1',
        'ajax' => array(
            'type'=>'POST', 
            'url'=>CController::createUrl('site/type'),             
            'data'=>array('type'=>'js:this.value'),
            'dataType'=>'html',
            'update' => '#receiver',
        ))); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'receiverType'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'receiver'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('receiver',$model->receiver,array()); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'subject'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'subject',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'subject'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'body'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'body',array('rows'=>10, 'cols'=>100,'style'=>'width: 60%')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'body'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('ارسال'); ?>
</div>

   <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

  </div><!-- form -->
```

controller

```
public function actionType()
{
    $Type=$_POST["type"];
    $contact=Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->select('id,email')
                ->from('contact')
                ->order('parent.email')
                ->queryAll();
    $data=CHtml::listData($contact,'id','email');
    if (!empty($data)) { echo '<option value="">choose...</option>'; }
    foreach($data as $value=>$name) {
        echo CHtml::tag('option',
                array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
        }
}
```

It works correctly but when i change this line:
CHtml::dropDownList('receiver',$model->receiver,array());
to this :
$form->dropDownList($model,'receiver',array());
it doesn't work any more.
how can i fix this problem?

Comment: Can you be more specific what "doesn't work any more" means to you? Is there an error message? Isn't the drop down rendering at all?

Comment: when I choose receiverType, receiver dropdownlist fill with the proper data and after I change that line, receiver dropdownlist remain empty.

Comment: what do you mean it doesnt work ? any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because the `id` of the drop down is no longer `#receiver`. You have 2 options:

1. Change the id to be update to the new id of the drop down i.e `#{Model_Name}_receiver`
2. Explicitly set the id of the drop down to `#receiver` through `htmlOptions`.

I'd go with the first one for consistency with the other inputs for the form.

Comment: Thank you very much. I try second solution and it works perfectly. but i don't know how can i examine first solution. should I change update to #model_receiver!?((sorry I'm new to Yii and I don't know how to write this). another question is should I change actionType function too?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a **can you write code** kind of site. However, I will tell you that, by default, the `id` for an active input field (of which `$form->dropDownList(..)` is an example) for an attribute `attr` for a model `ModelA` is `ModelA_attr`. Here is the API page http://yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail

Answer (score -2):

do u have reciever in your model ...

you have to have

```
// in a view  to use this
$form->dropDownList($model,'receiver',array()); 

// you should be having this in your
public $reciever; 
// it should be in your model to use it in view
```

and when you call ajax

```
  'ajax' => array(
        'type'=>'POST', 
        'url'=>CController::createUrl('site/type'),             
        'data'=>array('type'=>'js:this.value'),
        'dataType'=>'html',
       // 'update' => 'data.receiver',
        'update' => '#{id of reciver element perhaps it will be  
"#sendmessage-form_reciever"
```

to update **#sendmessage-form_reciever** which will be by default  id of that eklement

Comment: yes i have receiver in model. actually i have mistake in my post and i correct it.(update field in ajax was #receiver). with this it works fine. when i change CHtml::dropDownList to $form->dropDownList doesn't work.